# Cross tabulation. Count one column against another

Tags: mysql

I have a table with nine columns, I would like to do a order on one column, counting the frequency against another and listing the users that have performed that action and how many times.

The table is called table 1

So I would like to have in the end

<kbd>tcode</kbd><kbd>tcount</kbd><kbd>user</kbd>
<kbd>abc</kbd>      <kbd>9</kbd>      <kbd>user1</kbd>      
<kbd>abc</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>      <kbd>user2</kbd>      
<kbd>def</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      <kbd>user1</kbd>

So user one performed abc 9 times, user 2 4 times, user one also performed def 3 times

Comment: The expected result is clear, but how does your table look like?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the schema of the table containing the data, but your query has to look something like this :

```
select tcode, count(*) as tcount, user
from table1
group by tcode, user
```

Comment: Thanks, this done exactly what I wanted, I thought I was going to have to do nested queries to do it

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, most of nested queries have a simpler equivalent as a join.